# How to open iBoxDb server on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, database, mobile, windows-phone-8.1, nosql

I have found no documentation for iBoxDb and I don't know how to work with it on Windows Phone 8.1. The problem is InvalidOperationException says

```
"The API 'System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32)' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information."
```

How to make iBoxDb to use windows phone local storage api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iBoxDB doesn't support Windows Phone 8.1, and doesn't claim to on it's website; they only mention support for ".NET". The Windows Phone 8.1 SDK doesn't use System.IO.FileStream, so it's impossibly for iBoxDB to work unless the author changes the file access method. From what I can tell from the author's CodePlex page, iBoxDB hasn't been modified since 2013. It's probably best to look for a different NoSQL solution...

I would try something like KitaroDB that is known for supporting Windows Phone 8.1.
http://www.kitarodb.com